# Basic Mono<Map<String, String>> of WebFlux on handler class question

Tags: spring-webflux

This is the simple `Mono<Map<String, String>>` question of webflux. First the router class is

```
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routesUser(UserHandler handler) {

        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/all"), handler::findAll)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/route/user/login"), handler::authenticate);
```

And the next is the client codes of webclient.

```
Map<String, String> mapUser = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapUser.put("username", "joseph");
mapUser.put("password", "password");

client.post().uri("/route/user/login").body(Mono.just(mapUser), Map.class).exchange()
                .map(ClientResponse::statusCode).subscribe(response -> System.out.println("Login : " + response.getReasonPhrase()));
```

`Map<String, String> mapUser` is transfered to webflux handler class successfully.

I have the basic question on authenticate method of userhandler class.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> authenticate(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<Map<String, String>> monoMapUser = request.bodyToMono(Map.class);

        monoMapUser.map(m -> {
            return m.get("username");
        }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

`monoMapUser.subscribe(System.out::println)` prints the right username joseph.

How I can extract the username and password from monoMapUser like this?

```
String username = monoMapUser.map(m -> {return m.get("username");}.(????)
String password = monoMapUser.map(m -> {return m.get("password");}.(????)
```

Comment: why do you wanna extract it? whats the purpose and user case.

Comment: you should never `subscribe` in a webflux application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `map` or `flatMap` your `monoMapUser`

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> authenticate(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Map.class)
            .flatMap(map -> {
                map.get("username");
                map.get("password");

                //your logic

                return ServerResponse.ok().build();
            });
}
```